# How to create a function that reuses layout with making some changes

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I want to make an app like Instagram. It needs to publish posts with  images and  description text. From previous answers I understand , that i should create a post layout and use it for creating other posts. My question is : How can i create a function that helps me to create posts similar to my post_layout but with changed text and image? So i need a function that will help me to create posts using one template post layout. What will be the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse it by making "inflate" to the layout
but I would like to clarify that your return value will be of type "View"

Example:-

```
private View createPost(String text, Bitmap image){

   View createdPost = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_template,null);
   TextView tv_postTitle = createdPost.findViewById(R.id.fragment_post_tv_title);
   ImageView iv_postImage = createdPost.findViewById(R.id.fragment_post_iv_image);

   tv_postTitle.setText(text);
   iv_postImage.setImageBitmap(image);

   return createdPost;
   }
```

I hope this is useful